# Cannot find pg_hba.conf and postgreql.conf file on OS X?

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

I installed postgres using homebrew.
I would like to locate he files pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf but I cannot find them.

I followed this :

https://askubuntu.com/questions/256534/how-do-i-find-the-path-to-pg-hba-conf-from-the-shell

and this

http://www.kelvinwong.ca/tag/pg_hba-conf/

but I still cannot find it.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

By default homebrew, on intel Macs, puts everything in `/usr/local`

So the postgresql conf files will be  `/usr/local/var/postgres/`

If you are on an M1 Mac, brew will use a path like `/opt/homebrew/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf`

Comment: I am in my home directory, when I do cd /usr/local/var/postgres/ it says directory does not exist

Comment: How do I get to usr/ ?

Comment: is postgresql running?  (have you started the server), also take a look at `brew info posgtgresql` for more info

Comment: yes postgresql is running, i entered the /usr/local/var/postgres/ in finder but it gives me an empty directory.

Comment: thats strange when I do brew info it gives me 'No available formula for posgtgres '

Comment: posgtgresl as opposed to posrgres, and did you do an initdb ?  `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres`

Comment: i reinstalled brew and the info command works fine!, when I try so start the server I now get this 'FATAL:  lock file "postmaster.pid" already exists
HINT:  Is another postmaster (PID 1415) running in data directory "/usr/local/var/postgres"?' IS it because I reinstalled?

Comment: either look in Activity Monitor (in utilities) or `ps auxwww | grep post` to see if it is running. If it isn't running `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`, if it is running then it looks like you are trying to start another copy of the server and stop the old version first

Comment: `brew info postgresql` ... There was a typo in @Doon's comment.

Comment: @LoveMeow, `brew info postgresql@15`

Answer (score 32):

If you can connect to Pg as the superuser (usually `postgres`) simply `SHOW hba_file;` to see its location.

Otherwise you have to find out how PostgreSQL is started to locate its data directory.

Comment: This works when using an older Postgres version, since the configuration files are in a different named directory.  For example: /usr/local/var/postgresql@12/pg_hba.conf

Answer (score 13):

Worst case, you can search for it:

```
find / -type f -name pg_hba.conf 2> /dev/null
```

Comment: That finally solves my problem

Answer (score 12):

Whatever your OS is, you always can use the `psql` utility, DBeaver or any other client tool, and type the SQL `show` command to see the value of any run-time setting.

For example, on my BigSur OSX system, where I have installed PostgreSQL v13 with the EDB installer, these are the locations for `postgresql.conf` and `pg_hba.conf` files using the `psql` utility:

```
psql -U postgres -c 'show config_file'
Password for user postgres: 
                 config_file                 
---------------------------------------------
 /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data/postgresql.conf
(1 row)
```

```
psql -U postgres -c 'show hba_file'
Password for user postgres: 
                hba_file                 
-----------------------------------------
 /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data/pg_hba.conf
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 8):

This could be a possible location to find the postgresql.conf/pg_hba.conf file

```
/opt/homebrew/var/postgres/postgresql.conf  

/opt/homebrew/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf
```

Answer (score 6):

It's possible to edit those files without knowing their locations with pg admin
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61193/how-to-edit-postgresql-conf-with-pgadmin

> - To edit the postgresql.conf file:   Choose `Tools` > `Server Configuration` > `postgresql.conf`
> - To edit the pg_hba.conf file:  Choose `Tools` > `Server Configuration` > `pg_hba.conf`

Comment: To make that option active in the menu, I needed to connect to the relevant server and then click on the Databases item.

Answer (score 3):

In MacOS Catalina are under the folder:

```
 ./Library/PostgreSQL/{postgres_version}/share/postgresql/
```

Comment: Guess the dot before the first slash is not correct. This type of location corresponds to the EDB installation and is always at the `/Library/PostgreSQL/{version}/` folder

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to know the location of postgresql.conf is to start psql and type
\show all
Then search for the value of 'config_file'.
For my docker configuration, this will be  /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf 
then I can connect to Docker with
docker exec -it postgres bash -c "export TERM=xterm-256color ; bash"
and view its content with
cat /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf